# Node.JS: Trying to run docker project with docker-compose up exits due to node-sass and node-gyp

Tags: python, node.js, npm, docker-compose, node-sass

I'm trying to run one of my Docker work projects from MacBook Air M1 and I'm getting the following error while executing `docker-compose up`. Apparently **it can't find the python installation**, even though I can do both `python --version` and `python3 --version` from terminal. I'm relatively new to Docker but I tried to troubleshoot every possible thing to solve this error

```
#8 91.79 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
#8 91.79 error /app/node_modules/node-sass: Command failed.
#8 91.79 Exit code: 1
#8 91.79 Command: node scripts/build.js
#8 91.79 Arguments: 
#8 91.79 Directory: /app/node_modules/node-sass
#8 91.79 Output:
#8 91.79 Building: /usr/local/bin/node /app/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
#8 91.79 gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
#8 91.79 gyp verb cli [
#8 91.79 gyp verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/node',
#8 91.79 gyp verb cli   '/app/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
#8 91.79 gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
#8 91.79 gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
#8 91.79 gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
#8 91.79 gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
#8 91.79 gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
#8 91.79 gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
#8 91.79 gyp verb cli ]
#8 91.79 gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
#8 91.79 gyp info using node@16.13.0 | linux | arm64
#8 91.79 gyp verb command rebuild []
#8 91.79 gyp verb command clean []
#8 91.79 gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
#8 91.79 gyp verb command configure []
#8 91.79 gyp verb find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
#8 91.79 gyp verb find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
#8 91.79 gyp verb find Python checking if "python3" can be used
#8 91.79 gyp verb find Python - executing "python3" to get executable path
#8 91.79 gyp verb find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
#8 91.79 gyp verb find Python checking if "python" can be used
#8 91.79 gyp verb find Python - executing "python" to get executable path
#8 91.79 gyp verb find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
#8 91.79 gyp verb find Python checking if "python2" can be used
#8 91.79 gyp verb find Python - executing "python2" to get executable path
#8 91.79 gyp verb find Python - "python2" is not in PATH or produced an error
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! find Python 
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python2" can be used
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! find Python - "python2" is not in PATH or produced an error
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! find Python 
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="/path/to/pythonexecutable"
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "/path/to/pythonexecutable"
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! find Python 
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! configure error 
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (/app/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:302:47)
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (/app/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:136:21)
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:179:16)
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (/app/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:266:16)
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (node:child_process:404:5)
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (node:child_process:416:5)
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:288:12)
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! System Linux 5.10.47-linuxkit
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/app/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! cwd /app/node_modules/node-sass
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.0
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
#8 91.79 gyp ERR! not ok 
#8 91.79 Build failed with error code: 1
```

I tried all of the things that the error suggests - setting the path variable of the python, and trying to set NPM's config to the python's path but no luck...

I also tried downgrading node to v16, as node-sass 6.0.1 is not compatible with node v17 [according to the docs](https://github.com/sass/node-sass)

I have python 3.9.8 installed via homebrew, and running `which python3` outputs `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3`

`node -v`: **v16.13.0**

`npm -v`: **v8.1.0**

`echo $PATH`: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin /opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin`

`npm config list`:

```
prefix = "/opt/homebrew" 

; "global" config from /opt/homebrew/etc/npmrc

; python = "/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin" ; overridden by user

; "user" config from /Users/**username**/.npmrc

python = "/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin"
```

Comment: you have python installed inside your computer but it is not present in the docker container in which npm is running ... you need to install python in the container before the npm install process inside the same container ...

Comment: Or I am not sure if there is any way to use the python's container and link it in docker compose to the other container .. but in  gist of it .. python is installed on your mac but not inside the docker environment so you need to work around that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:**

The python is installed locally on your macbook but not inside the docker container (which is an isolated virtual os).

**Solution**

You need to install python in the same container where you are running the nodejs script or npm command.

Try Adding this after pulling your nodejs image in dockerFile

```
RUN apt-get update || : && apt-get install python -y
```

That is for debian or debian based linux distro ... (if you have official Node image that is based on debian so the upper line should work fine right after you pull the image run you need to install python in the same container).

Comment: In my case, adding `RUN apk add --update python3 make g++\
   && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*` before yarn in dockerFile solved the issue. Still curious how the same container works fine on other machines without this...

Comment: @Stepan you are using the alphine version ... and the same problem will occur any where if the python is not installed .. because node-sass requires node-gyp for native compilation and node-gyp needs python for interpretation .. :) The toturial guy probably missed it or he may not be using node-sass or any native module.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution

```sh
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install sass -S -D
```

> Node Sass to Dart Sass
> Before v4.3.0, this project was built based on node-sass, but node-sass low-level dependencies libsass, resulting in many users installing Especially difficult for Windows users, it forces users to install python2 and Visual Studio in the windows environment to compile successfully.
>
> So in order to solve this problem, this project was modified to build
> dart-sass in v4.3.0, it can guarantee performance Under the premise of
> greatly simplifying the user's installation costs. Through this issue
> the relevant comments below can be known, install` Node-sass is such a
> troublesome thing.
>
> There is a more important reason for choosing to use dart-sass here.
> Officially, sass has taken dart-sass as the main development direction
> in the future. Any new features will be supported first, and it It has
> been running steadily in the community for a long time, and there are
> basically no pits. The main reason why dart-sass is easy to install is
> because it will be compiled into pure js, so that it can be used
> directly in the node environment. Although its running speed will be
> slower than that based on libsass, the difference in these speeds is
> almost negligible. The entire community is now embracing dart-sass,
> and we have no reason to refuse! And it does greatly simplify the
> user's installation costs.
>
> Currently, vue-cli will also prefer to use dart-scss by default when
> selecting sass preprocessing, related: pr

https://panjiachen.github.io/vue-element-admin-site/guide/advanced/sass.html#upgrade-plan